# Iterating same json (dict) file twice in for loop

Tags: python, json, for-loop

so I have json file which I need to get two different strings to different files.
First one is is going to the file as it should but the second is not.

I've made my research and I know that I need to move the file pointer back to start. But I just don't know how to do it. Because I'll just get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "v4.py", line 65, in <module>
    data.seek(0,0)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'seek'
```

when trying to move it back with `.seek(0)`

```
with open('idd.json', 'r') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

with open('id.txt','w') as outfile:
    for data, lokaatio in data[0].items():
        if data=='id':
            print(lokaatio, file=outfile)

data.seek(0,0)

with open('type.txt','w') as outfiles:
    for data, type in data[0].items():
        if data=='fileType':
            print(type, file=outfiles)
```

How do you move json(dict) file to start for new search..

---

Update:

Now, there is no error, but the second file remains empty. (Thank you for the shortened code lines!)

The fileType is not found by the python. Is the only remaining solution that there is something wrong in my file? It looks about like this:

[{**'id': 'BDB-0bxGag9AL_C4xB0hlM'**,'versionNumber': 1}, {'widthMm': 127.0, 'heightIn': 5.0, 'width': 1500}, {'documentId': 'xmp.483a0ab5', **'fileType': 'JPEG'**, 'heightMm': 127.0}, 'permissions': ’rx——’}]

Comment: The problem is with `for data, lokaatio in ...`: you re-use the data variable name so the old one is overwritten. It originally held a dictionary, no need for the seek(0).

Comment: `data` is not a file object. You simply re-used the name in the `for` loop to bind it to a string.

Comment: Could you add `print(data)` after `data` loaded from file and post results?

Comment: The problem is that the fileType is under the metadata field, that is why it is empty. The script is doing its job. Like this: 'metadata': {'fileType': JPG,...
So I need to take the full metadata first and make file from it, then read it one last time to get into fileType..

Answer (score 0):

After line

```
data = json.load(data_file)
```

variable `data` will contain `dict`, not `file`. And your code (except `data.seek(0,0)` which is wrong) are almost fine. Your problem lay at

```
for data, lokaatio in data[0].items():
```

You redefine `data` variable. Try to replace this with

```
with open('id.txt','w') as outfile:
    for d, lokaatio in data[0].items():
        if d=='id':
            print(lokaatio, file=outfile)
```

Also, loop over `dict` is unnecessary (thanks to comment of @Jean-François Fabre). You could just get element by key.

```
with open('id.txt','w') as outfile:
    print(data.get('id', ''), file=outfile)
```

Same for second loop

```
with open('type.txt','w') as outfiles:
    print(data.get('fileType', ''), file=outfiles)
```

All your code could be replaced with

```
with open('idd.json', 'r') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

with open('id.txt','w') as idfile, open('type.txt','w') as typefile:
    print(data.get('id', ''), file=idfile)
    print(data.get('fileType', ''), file=typefile)
```

Comment: why looping on the dict items to search for the key? that seems lidicrious. no need for a loop.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre Agree, thanks for comment. Will update answer

Comment: @E.W See my updates. And add new problem description to your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to loop twice, just use a simple if, elif statement and open your two files together. Like this:

```
with open('idd.json', 'r') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

with open('id.txt','w') as outfile1, open('type.txt','w') as outfile2 :
    for key,value in data[0].items(): # or is your dict in data.items()?
        if key =='id':
            print(value, file=outfile1)
        elif key =='fileType':
            print(value, file=outfile2)
```